# Symfony2 AJAX validation

Tags: jquery, ajax, validation, symfony, jquery-validate

I'm using Symfony2 components and Doctrine. Validation works great on server side (constraints in Entities etc.) What I want is to validate form (my own custom built without using Symfony Form component) via AJAX.

Is there any way to use Validation component to validate fields using AJAX?

Or I should use jQuery validation plugin? Which seems not logical since then there will be 2 different validations used.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can send the serialized form via AJAX and return the rendered form from the server side if it contains validation errors.

```
$.post($form.attr('action'), $form.serialize(), function (response) {
    if (response.success) {
        // do something on success
    } else {
        $form.replaceWith(response.form);
    }
});
```

On the server side you check if it's an AJAX request and return `response` in the JSON format.

Comment: Thank you for the answer @elnur. This is also what I think but in this way I need to submit form to see errors. I want it more like jQuery Validate plugin when user starts typing for example email and if it's not correct - message is shown. But I don't want to make an AJAX request on each keypress.

Comment: Since it doesn't make sense to send a list of all registered emails to JS on the first page load — because of security and other issues — you'll have to make an AJAX request anyway. You just should do it not on each keypress, but after some timout or `change` event.